# how to disable select view in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ui-select

I want to disable the ui multiple select view  whenever I select particaular value in my  example "Nicole" .If I select "Nicole" it disable the ui select then user not able to select other option.

can we remove previous selected option when user select "Nicole" .? I want only if user select "Nicole" it disable the select view and remove other selected option .

plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/eVXVzlRXJ4KUZaNjID6P?p=preview

```
$scope.OnClickSelect = function(item) {
    $scope.multipleDemo.push(item.age)
}

$scope.OnRemoveSelect = function(item) {
    var index = $scope.multipleDemo.indexOf(item.age);
    $scope.multipleDemo.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Comment: so if you select nicole you cant able to select the other options right ? is this your problem

Comment: yes ..that is problem..correct and also if user selected any previous option it remove all options

Comment: are you sure, but in your plunkr link am able to select Nicole as well as other options too will you please check the plunkr link

Comment: that why I asked the Question

Comment: ohh I got it, you want to disable the options after the nicole has been selected right

Comment: yes ...correct ..one more thing I want if user select first "abc" then "nicole."I want to remove "abc" from model aslo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124500/discussion-between-user944513-and-m-balajivaishnav).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forked your plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/iEPTmi).

**index.html**

I changed

```
ng-disabled="disable"
```

to

```
ng-disabled="isDisabled()"
```

**demo.js**

```
$scope.disabled = false;

$scope.OnClickSelect = function(item) {
  if (item.name === 'Nicole') {
    // Check to make sure there is a previous user to remove
    if ($scope.multipleDemo.length > 0) {
      $scope.multipleDemo.pop();
    }
    // Disable user picker
    $scope.disabled = true;
  }
  $scope.multipleDemo.push(item.age);
}

$scope.isDisabled = function() {
  return $scope.disabled;
}
```

Currently, when you select "Nicole" it disables the ui select picker and it removes the previously added user from the list `multipleDemo`. For some reason, it's removing the previously added user from `multipleDemo` list but it's not removing it from the UI. The digest cycle is not updating properly. Might it worth it to try it in your project to see if it gets updated properly there.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Modified OnClickSelect function call to OnClickSelect($item, $select) and added disabled in scope. $select variable will hepl us to manipulate the selected data.

use **on-select="OnClickSelect($item, $select)"** and **ng-disabled="disabled"** in ui-select tag.

```
$scope.disabled = false;
$scope.restrictNames = ["Nicole", "Michael"];

$scope.OnClickSelect=function(item, $select)
{
  if($scope.restrictNames.indexOf(item.name) != -1){
    $select.selected = [];
    $scope.multipleDemo = [];
    $scope.disabled = true;
  }
  $scope.multipleDemo.push(item.age);
}
```

Comment: please share plunker